# copyable data class in C++

Tags: c++, dynamic, memory-management, class-design, deep-copy

Inspired by [this article](http://www.codedread.com/blog/archives/2005/03/23/writing-copyable-c-classes/), I have a class which contains a nested copyable data class. This copyable class has no dynamic memory allocation, protect or private for its member class.

```
Class Domain
{
public:
    // copyable class
    struct CopyableDataClass
    { 
        int i; 
    }
    void method1(const CopyableDataClass& data){...}
    void method2(const CopyableDataClass& data){...}
}
```

Also, by reading [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy), I could not use dynamic memory allocation for "CopyableDataClass" itself, to avoid the shallow copy, like

```
Domain::CopyableDataClass* p1=new CopyableDataClass();
Domain::CopyableDataClass* p2;
p2=p1;
```

But what about the "Domain" Class, is it also special, e.g., can I do it as follows?

```
Class User
{
public:
    Domain* getter();
    void setter(const Domain* data);
private:
    Domain* m_data; //pointer ok? private ok?
}
```

Or I have to put it into public like the copyable class,

```
Class User
{
public:
    Domain m_data; 
}
```

Besides the general class design rule (encapsulation, etc.), is there any constraint (protect/private/dynamic memory allocation) to the usage of this "Domain" class. I guess the constraints only apply to the "Copyable" class. Am I right?

Thanks for any comments.

Comment: You shouldn't declare public member variables. In addition, you can't declare the pointer to the domain-object with the const qualifier in your setter method, when you assign it to your non-const member.

Comment: Hi, FrEEzE2046, first, thanks for your comment. But are you talking about general class design rule or something specific to my question?

Comment: I'm not totally sure I understand your question, but if `Foo` is a POD class (or something sufficiently simple), then you can have direct `Foo` members of other classes without having to worry much about copying the member, but of course your ambient class can be as complex as you like.

Comment: Domain::CopyableDataClass* p1=new CopyableDataClass();
Domain::CopyableDataClass* p2;
p2=p1; this is not a "shallow copy" you are simply copying a pointer, you get a shallow copy (for example) when your class has a pointer to dynamic allocated object and your assignment operator copy just the pointer instead of allocate a new object with the same value

Comment: "You shouldn't declare public member variables" is a good general class design rule. The other issue is specific to the code you have written--you can't assign a const to a non-const without casting the const away, which defeats the point of making it const.

Comment: Maybe another general remark: Recursive rules for building things from simpler things go "down", not "up": For instance, a class is POD only if all its members are POD ("down"), but there is no constraint on what you can do with the class itself.

Comment: @pepero - Nobody stopps you from declaring a public member variable, but you should never do it. However, your compiler will stop you from assigning a const object reference / pointer to an non-const one.

Comment: you're missing a semi-colon after `struct CopyableDataClass{}`

Comment: Please, guys, I definitely know "do not declare public member variables", etc. What I am interested is if there is anything special to be consider for a class, which contains a copyable class inside. If possible, please read the article and answer the question in specific.

Answer (score 2):

Your `CopyableDataClass` is like a value, similar to an `int`. There is nothing much to gain from allocating it dynamically, just like you generally don't do that with single `int`s.

If your `Domain` class contains just "copyable data" it will be just as copyable as its content.

Answer (score 0):

Your user class should look like that:

```
class user
{
public:
    // we can't construct a domain-user without knowing it's domain
    user(Domain* domain) : m_domain(domain) { }

    // return the domain the user is part of
    Domain& get_domain() { return *this->m_domain; }

private:
    // you can't copy a domain-user
    user(user const&);
    user& operator=(user const&);

    Domain* m_domain;
};
```

Comment: This code will not compile, because `get_domain` is declared to return a reference, but returns a pointer. You should use a reference throughout, there is no need for a pointer here.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y -  You should take a closer look at `get_domain`. It doesn't return a pointer. Furthermore, you cannot store a `m_domain` as a reference and you shouldn't store a copy of something like that.

Answer (score 0):

For the copy semantic I usually follow these rules:

1) if my class is a POD I can use the compiler generated copy constructor and assignment operator.

2) if I want to prevent copies of my object, I declare copy constructor and assignment operator private and I don't implement them

3) if my class is not a POD I provide my implementation of copy constructor and assignment operator that provide a deep copy of the object. When an object has const data members I declare the assignment operator private and I don't implement it.